# Round Corner is not working in Material Button

Tags: android, material-design, android-button, material-components-android

I have button like this in my login activity layout.

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/button_login_activity"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Login"
                app:cornerRadius="20dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textColor="@color/toolbar_text"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/button_skip_login_activity"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cornerRadius="20dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:textColor="@color/toolbar_text"
                android:text="Skip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

        </LinearLayout>
```

My Style is like this

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!--Common Color-->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogTheme</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">@color/switch_normal</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/switch_normal</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/switch_normal</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>

    </style>
```

I have dependency like below

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
```

I have tried many things but unable to make it working for round corner, same thing is working for my another project. Let me know if anyone can help me for come out from the issue.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to **remove** the background:

```
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
```

Using it the `MaterialButton` doesn't use its own `MaterialShapeDrawable` for the background. This means that features like shape appearance, stroke and rounded corners are ignored.

In your case use the **`app:backgroundTint`** attribute:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
```